# Jquery upload file doesnt work in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, requirejs, jquery-file-upload

Im using requirejs, html5 and jquery file upload to upload files :

```
myUpload = function (){
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        add: function (e, data) {

            var goUpload = true;
            var uploadFile = data.files[0];
            if (!(/\.(pdf|png|jpeg|jpg)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
                goUpload = false;
            }
            if (uploadFile.size > 5000000) { // 2mb

                goUpload = false;
            }
            if (goUpload === true) {

            data.submit();
            } 
        }, url: '../myUrl',
           done: function (e, data) {
                data.context.text('Upload done.');
       }
});
```

here is the HTML code:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple
                                            data-sequential-uploads="true">
```

so my solution works on Firefox and Google Chrome.
Now im trying to make it work on IE8, when I choose my file IE8 block immediately the operation!
Any suggestions?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: IE 8 do not supports html5

Comment: IE8 supports some HTML5 features but not file API

Comment: isn't the file upload plugin supposed to get around that issue using an iframe?

Comment: @KevinB Which plugin? This one should: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score 0):

Just set the content-type of the response to text/html and send it as JSON.

This should work for all browsers.